# how to check values between two columns?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have two columns in a table where I need to check if any value is present between them. If yes I need to return that value.

For example

```
user_id | role_id
 1        2
 3        4
 5        nil
 nil      6
```

If there are values in both columns then I should return any of them. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can return both if both have values and not null

`select * from Table where user_id NOT NULL AND role_id NOT NULL`